# Scala: How to count how many times a Future pair succeded

Tags: scala, future

In the following code snippet invokes `getAmounts` to get some amounts grouped by currency and then invokes `getRates` to apply the corresponding exchange rate:

```
def getAmounts = Future(Map("EUR" -> 500d, "USD" -> 400d))
def getRates = Future(Map("EUR" -> 1d, "USD" -> 0.9))

getAmounts.flatMap { amounts =>
  getRates.map { rates =>
    amounts.foldLeft(0d)((total, amount) => total + (amount._2 * rates(amount._1)))
  }
}.map { println(_) }
```

Here is the output (500.0 * 1 + 400 * 0.9):

```
860.0
```

How do I get the number of amounts processed (in this case 2)? The count should be increased if and only of both `Future`s succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about returning a `Tuple2` in your `fold` that contains the total and the count:

```
amounts.foldLeft((0d, 0))
  ((accum, amount) => (accum._1 + (amount._2 * rates(amount._1)),accum._2 + 1))
```